# missing resolution in ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, resolution, devices

I have a NVida GT 630M in my laptop. I tried to install the graphics driver by using the following command :

```
sudo nvidia
```

After installing I face a serious problem with the resolution:
The only one available is 640*480. What should I do, to have my graphical device correctly installed.

Comment: I don't know any command called `nvidia` that is related to the common NVidia drivers. Please post where you got this from.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to install the NVidia drivers in 12.04 is with the restricted drivers manager. Go to `System Settings`->`Additional Drivers` and install the drivers from there. If you want to do it from the terminal the command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```